# How to display labels with matplotlib and networkx

Tags: python, graph, label, networkx

I'm really beginner for setting up development environment and programing.
I had installed networkx and matplotlib with anaconda.
But when I try to display graph, it cannot display labels like this picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyPWl.png)

And this is code.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.Graph()

g.add_node(2)
g.add_node(5)

g.add_edge(2,5)

g.add_edge(4,1)

g.add_edges_from([(2,5),(1,3)])

nx.draw(g)

plt.show()
```

As I looked up about this error, it seems that I should change backend.
But I'm not really sure how to change it.
It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain the details. 
I'm using MAC and Python3.6, anaconda.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nx.draw_networkx(g)` instead of `nx.draw(g)` because the latter does not draw labels.

Comment: `nx.draw ()` does not display labels, but `nx.draw_networkx ()` does. Why isn't this an answer???

Comment: @DYZ Add that information (difference between draw and draw_networkx) in your answer.

Comment: Yes. I could make it !! Thank you very much for your answer !!